# programmatically change style on placeholder control

Tags: asp.net

is there a way to programmatically set style on PlaceHolder control?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct setter for it however you can use Attributes parameter.

```
Dim panel As Panel = New Panel()
panel.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;")
```

Answer (score 0):

A place holder will not render itself, just whatever has been placed in it.

If you want to render the container use Panel instead.  Panels will render as divs.

```
panel.CssClass = "SomeClass";
```

Comment: does it mean the placeholder control cannot have dynamic css style?

Comment: btw.. can you actually have 2 divs in place holder with one has text allign to left and the other one to right? been trying this but no luck

Comment: True, the placeholder can not have css.  And yeah you should be able to put divs inside one